# router.isFallback changes true to false

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My enviroment is here:

| Environment | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Rails | 7.0.0 |
| React | 18.0 |
| Next.js | 12.1.4 |

My setting of `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` are here:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/admin/users_data`
  );

  const paths = data.data.users.map((user: any) => {
    return { params: { id: user.id.toString() } };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (params: any) => {
  const users = params.params.id;
  return {
    props: { users },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
};
```

I want to add users and can access the detail page after `next build`.

I heard that I can achieve it using `revalidate` and `fallback: true`.

I wrote an error option if there is no path.

```
import ErrorPage from "next/error";

export default function UsersDetailPage(props: {
  users: any;
}) {
  const router = useRouter();

  return !router.isFallback && props.users ? (
// UsersDetailPage
  ) : (
    <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />
  );
}
```

From this code when I access to wrong path directly, showing an error page in few seconds.

parameter is this:

```
props.users: undefined
router.isFallback: true
```

[image]

But after that, parameter will change to

```
props.users: example // <-- not existing
router.isFallback: false
```

And show the detail page.

I can't understand what's going on.

Can you teach me how I can solve the problem?

Thank you.

### Update

[image]

Comment: Which Next.js version are you using? `revalidate` is only available from 9.5

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using `12.1.4`.

Comment: You should handle the 404 page inside `getStaticProps` instead, by returning `{ notFound: true }` if `users` is undefined there.

Comment: You mean change ` <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />` to `{ notFound: true }` in JSX?

Comment: For me, the solution was to add `{notFound: true, revalidate: 10}` inside `getStaticProps` along with `{fallback: "blocking" }` inside `getStaticPaths`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Big thanks for @Nick Vu and @MLDC.

It was really helpful for me.

All the cause of bug is here:

```
export const getStaticProps = async (params: any) => {
  const users = params.params.id; // <-- here!!
  return {
    props: { users },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
};
```

Seems next.js must fetch data from server-side in getStaticProps section.

So I fix to:

```
export const getStaticProps = async (params: any) => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/admin/user_edit/${params.params.id}`
  );
  //<-- here!
  const users = data.data.user;
  return {
    props: { users },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
};
```

Then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try to refactor your code like this first (assuming fallback in getStaticPaths is set to true)

```
import ErrorPage from "next/error";

export default function UsersDetailPage(props: {
  users: any;
}) {
  const router = useRouter();

  if(router.isFallback){
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return UsersDetailPage;
```

If the user data is not yet available, it would result **router.isFallback** to true. Thereafter, it will show a Loading div until the data is readily available. If this works, change the **div** to your ErrorPage. But I would suggest that a **loading state** would be better to show to a user instead of a 404 page.

docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-pages

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

If your path is defined in `getStaticPaths` but no user data from the API calls, you can show 404 with `props.user` check. With this solution, you can use `revalidate: 10` and `fallback: 'blocking'` for the revalidation mechanism.

```
import ErrorPage from "next/error";

export default function UsersDetailPage(props: {
  users: any;
}) {

  if(!props.users) {
     return <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />
  }

  return <UsersDetailPage/>
}
```

If your paths are not defined during build-time and you strictly block requests from users accessing non-defined paths, you can set [`fallback: false`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-false) to serve 404 instead of your user profile component

> If fallback is false, then any paths not returned by getStaticPaths will result in a 404 page.

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/admin/users_data`
  );

  const paths = data.data.users.map((user: any) => {
    return { params: { id: user.id.toString() } };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false, //if the path is not defined, we will show 404
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (params: any) => {
  const users = params.params.id;
  return {
    props: { users },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
};
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

I think you misunderstand between `fallback: true` and `fallback: 'blocking'`

[`fallback: true`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true) does not return 404 but will return a fallback page which is expected, and generate HTML later (subsequent requests will be served with new generated HTML instead of a fallback page)

> The paths that have not been generated at build time will not result in a 404 page.

[`fallback: 'blocking'`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-blocking) (is only available from Next.js version 12+) goes along with `revalidate`. if your path is not defined, it will try to fetch the data and won't return a fallback page (like server-side rendering but cache your page for later usage)

> The paths that have not been generated at build time will not result in a 404 page. Instead, Next.js will SSR on the first request and return the generated HTML.

You can check [this release note](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#bot-aware-isr-fallback) from Next.js 12

> Currently, Incremental Static Regeneration with fallback: true renders a fallback state before rendering the page contents on the first request to a page that was not generated yet. To block the page from loading (server-rendering), you would need to use fallback: 'blocking'.

Your code may be like below

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/admin/users_data`
  );

  const paths = data.data.users.map((user: any) => {
    return { params: { id: user.id.toString() } };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    //fallback: true, //serve the fallback page and then generate HTML later
    fallback: 'blocking', //fetch data first and generate HTML on the server
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (params: any) => {
  const users = params.params.id;
  return {
    props: { users },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I changed `fallback:true` to `fallback: "blocking"` but doesn't work...

Comment: And not showing an error page anymore..

Comment: you may need to check the response from the server by `console.log`. It won't serve the fallback page, so you need to remove this condition `router.isFallback` @Hinoarashi

Comment: Put `console.log(params.params.id)` inside getStaticProps. It shows path which I accessed. for example, if I access `http://localhost:3001/admin/users/example`, it would show `example`. anyway, if I remove `router.isFallback`, how can I show 404 page? I want to block accessing from wrong path. Sorry I don't have enough knowledge and don't know what I should...

Comment: You want to show 404 if the path is not defined in `getStaticPaths`? @Hinoarashi

Comment: by the way, I updated my answer for 404 check, you can look into it again, @Hinoarashi

Comment: umm.. kind of yes. But there is create users function. so after creating a user, we 
can access user detail page. That's why I'm using `revalidate`.  In short what I want to do is ① after creating a user, we can access 
 `http://localhost:3001/admin/users/user_id` even after `next build`. ② blocking from wrong path which is not invalid user_id.

Comment: This code `if(!props.users) {return <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />}` also help you if `revalidate: 10` and `fallback: 'blocking'` are there, @Hinoarashi

Comment: Sorry.. it failed again.. if I access with wrong `user_id` like a or b or c, I can access to the user detail page. And it seems creating new path by wrong user_id. I don't know why.. What's more, `console.log(params.params.id)` which inside getStaticProps shows wrong user_id I typed.

Comment: >it seems creating new path by wrong user_id.   <-- because first few seconds show 404 page but after that redirecting user detail page. maybe creating new path by next.js?

Comment: but user data is not there, `props.user` is undefined, right? @Hinoarashi

Comment: Yes, But after few seconds change `undefined` to path what I typed..

Comment: what is your `fallback` value right now? if it's `fallback:true`, you will get the fallback page for a while, and if it cannot fetch user data, it will trigger `if(props.users)` as undefined. Could you put `console.log(props.users)` before `if(!props.users)`? @Hinoarashi

Comment: I did `export default function UsersDetailPage(props: { ... }) { const router = useRouter();

  console.log(props.users);
  console.log(router.isFallback);` and update my question. you can see what's going on from gif.

Comment: Sorry making gif takes long time.. now updated.

Comment: @Hinoarashi the first request is correct because user data is undefined, the second request has user data, so it will return user details. You can check [this doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-pages). It will serve the fallback with loading, and then whenever your API fetch on the server completed (with user data), it will render your user detail page